# How to use a ValueEventListener to only generate a tost for when new children are added, but not for already existing children? Any Ideas?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So, I am creating an android app with firebase, where I am using a ValueEventListener() to display a list of all children. But I also want to generate a toast(which I am later going to convert into a notification) when a new child is added. For which I am using a ChildEventListener(), but the problem here is that it also makes toast for all the already existing children when i startup the app(which i do not want). I decided to us the childEventListener() since its onChildAdded() method only gives info about a new child. Can anyone suggest any Ideas/solutions? I want to implement this without firebase functions. Here is the activity.

```
package com.example.draft_app;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FaceLogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_face_log);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("App").child("Faces");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Faces face = snapshot.getValue(Faces.class);
                    String txt = face.getIdentity() + " : " + face.getTime();
                    list.add(txt);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                Faces face = snapshot.getValue(Faces.class);
                String txt = face.getIdentity() + " : " + face.getTime();
                Toast.makeText(FaceLogActivity.this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you are adding all the time, are you sure you are not inserting a value which is supposed to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you listen both for `child_` and for `value` events on the same node, the `value` event will always fire last. You can use this knowledge to built you use-case, because you can use the `onDataChange` to set a flag, that you then check in `onChildAdded`.

Something like:

```
// add a field to the class
bool isInitialDataReceived = false

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("App").child("Faces");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Faces face = snapshot.getValue(Faces.class);
                String txt = face.getIdentity() + " : " + face.getTime();
                list.add(txt);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            isInitialDataReceived = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
           throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
        }
    });

    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            if (isInitialDataReceived) {
                Faces face = snapshot.getValue(Faces.class);
                String txt = face.getIdentity() + " : " + face.getTime();
                Toast.makeText(FaceLogActivity.this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) { }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) { }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
           throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
        }
    });

}
```